# Error occurs on starting unit test using karma/ jasmine for angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am having trouble running the unit tests. I simply trying to run unit test and it throws following error -

```
~\gulp\unit-tests.js:28
      throw err;
            ^
Error in plugin '←[36mgulp-karma←[39m'
karma exited with code 1
    at done (C:\WorProj\S1SurveyClient\S1SurveyClient\node_modules\gulp-karma\in
dex.js:56:30)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\WorProj\S1SurveyClient\S1SurveyClient\node_m
odules\gulp-karma\index.js:82:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to add the path to the tests to karma.conf.js. Something like this:

```
files: ['target/test/*.spec.js'],
```